# How can I increase the speed of the cursor in Gnome terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Compared to the getty tty's the cursor speed in Gnome Terminal feels slow and sluggish.
By cursor speed I mean if say you were in the middle of a long line at a command prompt and you held down <kbd>⬅</kbd> - how fast the cursor travels as well and general scrolling etc.
Yes if know you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to get to the start of a long line also - but I want to speed up the cursor speed in general.
Is this possible using gnome terminal or possibly using `xset`, e.g to slow down mouse pointer speed I typically use `xset m 3/2 5`.
If I dump xset, with `xset q` I get

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  33
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
```

Does the value of `repeat rate` affect terminal cursor speed? otherwise, how can I increase cursor speed of gnome terminal?

Comment: Yes, it effects. E.g. use `xset r rate 300 50` to wait for 300 ms between emitting the letter for the first and the second time, and then emit it 50 times per second.

Comment: @egmont thanks, this works for me. Do you know  if `xset r rate 300 50` will persist over reboots etc?

Comment: Most likely not. However, there's a corresponding graphical setting (in case of Gnome) in System Settings -> Keyboard which should be restored.

Answer (score 4):

The cursor move speed is related to your keyboard's repetition rate you can use `kbdrate` to change it but it will change it globally.

```
sudo kbdrate
```

will give you the current settings

```
Usage: kbdrate [-V] [-s] [-r rate] [-d delay]
```

I'm not really sure on this .. didn't look into it but I found that the delay is the time before the repeating starts and the rate is the speed of repeating ..the rate seems limited from 2 to 30.

I also do not really know the function of the -s switch ... I thought it was set but I was wrong since when using it .. the values didn't seem to change .. I had to use the command

```
sudo kbdrate -r 10
```

or

```
sudo kbdrate -d 250
```

to have the settings change.

This doesn't seem to be working in 16.04... I looked into it some more and also found you can try editing your X Server config

The option to look for would be

```
Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    Option         "AutoRepeat" "<delay> <rate>".
EndSection
```

Comment: thanks, I'm testing it now. From the man  page: `-s     Silent.  No messages are printed`

Comment: Unfortunately its not working for me on 16.04

Comment: I seemed to not notice a difference if I tried to change my rate either .. after posting this I was playing with it ... and I guess i may delete this answer because yeah .. it doesn't seem to be functioning anymore in the newer versions

Comment: `kbdrate` is for the Linux text mode console. For the graphical (X11) environment you need `xset r`.

Comment: is it  `kbdrate` for ubuntu 16.04 LTS terminal or `xset r` ? And what's the right setting ?  there don't seem to be a clear answer here. Thanks

Comment: For 16.04 you can use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 150`

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "Settings" by clicking on the gear icon in the top-right
   corner of the screen.
2. In the "Settings" window, click on "Universal Access" from the left
   sidebar.
3. Under "Typing," you'll find the "Repeat Keys" option. Adjust the
   "Delay" and "Speed" sliders to your desired settings.
4. The "Delay" slider controls how long you need to hold a key before
   it starts repeating. The "Speed" slider controls how fast the cursor
   moves when holding down the cursor keys. Once you've adjusted the
   settings to your preference, close the "Settings" window, and the
   changes should take effect immediately.
   [image: enter code here]
   [image: enter code here]